# Get difference between two dates using JS issue

Tags: javascript, date

Having a really weird issue I can't pinpoint.  I've tried a few different variations to get the number of days between two dates in JS.  For the most part (99% of the time), the below works great, but I've been getting some incorrect results **sometimes when I cross over months.  For example, if I get the amount of days between July 31st, 2015 and August 1st, 2015, it correctly returns 1.  However, if I try to grab the amount of days between June 30th, 2015 and July 1st, 2015 I get the result of 2 days (there are only 30 days in June, I've double checked).  Is this something with my server environment or am I going crazy?

```
start_date = new Date(start); // assuming the format is correct
end_date = new Date(ends); // assuming the format is correct
diff_ms = end_date.getTime() - start_date.getTime(); 
var days = diff_ms / 86400000;
```

I've also tried the following and got the exact same results:

```
start_date = new Date(start); // assuming the format is correct
end_date = new Date(ends); // assuming the format is correct
var timeDiff = Math.abs(end_date.getTime() - start_date.getTime());
var days = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Comment: What exactly do your starting strings look like when you get strange answers?

Comment: I get `1`: `var d1 = new Date(2015, 05, 30); var d2 = new Date(2015, 06, 1); (d2-d1)/86400000;`.

Comment: You could start by not assuming the format is correct. Show an example of  what the actual input is. It's also a bit dangerous to assume a day has exactly 24 hours; it's not always true (think e.g. daylight savings time).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers.  The dates are being pulled from an input on change.  The input is in format mm-dd-yyyy and here is the first part of the script: `from = jQuery("#from").val().split("-");
 start = new Date(from[2], from[0], from[1] - 1);
 to = jQuery("#to").val().split("-");
 ends = new Date(to[2], to[0], to[1] - 1);`

Comment: @GabeN the script is not as interesting as the actual date strings that are causing problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: start_date = new Date(2015, 06, 30); 
end_date = new Date(2015, 07, 1); I also got 2 with this one

Comment: @RodrigoLópez months are numbered from zero - June is 5, July is 6

Comment: Maybe he had the same confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pointy & @Rodrigo, you guys both led me to the problem.  I was aware that months started at zero but I incorrectly wrote the initial script and subtracted a day from the **Day not from the **Month.  It should have been:

```
from = jQuery("#from").val().split("-");
start = new Date(from[2], from[0] - 1, from[1]);
to = jQuery("#to").val().split("-");
ends = new Date(to[2], to[0] - 1, to[1]);
```

Thanks for the help!